# Functional equation: $f(x) = x + 1 + \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x+2)}$ , $f(t) = 0$?

Tags: numerical-methods, functional-equations, closed-form, continued-fractions

Consider

$$f(x) = x+1+\dfrac{x+2+\dfrac{x+3+\dfrac{x+4+\cdots}{x+5+\cdots}}{x+4+\dfrac{x+5+\cdots}{x+6+\cdots}}} {x+3+\dfrac{x+4+\dfrac{x+5+\cdots}{x+6+\cdots}}{x+5+\dfrac{x+6+\cdots}{x+7+\cdots}}} $$

This implies

$$f(x) = x + 1 + \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x+2)}$$

And for large positive real $x$ , $f(x)$ is close to $x + 2$

We know the inequality for $f(0)$

$$\sqrt 3 > 1+\dfrac{2+\dfrac{3+\dfrac{4+\cdots}{5+\cdots}}{4+\dfrac{5+\cdots}{6+\cdots}}} {3+\dfrac{4+\dfrac{5+\cdots}{6+\cdots}}{5+\dfrac{6+\cdots}{7+\cdots}}} $$

See : [Simplifying a complicated continued fraction expression.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4664497/simplifying-a-complicated-continued-fraction-expression)

What I wonder about is this

$f(t) = 0$

where $t$ is the largest solution.

**
edit : with large(st) I mean the usual ordering of the reals ; so $-1$ is larger than $-2$ , not some kind of absolute value thing. Just to be clear.
**

I estimate $t = - \frac{1 + \gamma }{2} $ or about $- 0,53860783245..$ but that is a very brute estimate.

Do we know a closed form for $t$ ?

***edit***

I found this :

[Functional equation: $f(x)=x+\dfrac{f(2x)}{f(3x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876645/functional-equation-fx-x-dfracf2xf3x)

Maybe it relates ?

Comment: can you find the values of $f$ on the integers?

Comment: I tried Mathematica to see the largest root.  ```f[0, x_] := 1 + x; 
f[n_, x_] := 
 1 + x + f[n - 1, x + 1]/f[n - 1, x + 2]; Table[{NumberForm[
   FindRoot[f[n, x], {x, -1.5}], 15]}, {n, 1, 15}]```

Comment: it seems the root is ```-1.5185960265866827```

Comment: @Yimin that might be a root but is it the largest root ? Or did you mean -$0.5189..$ ? How did you compute your value ?  For small truncations I got around $-0.52$

Comment: @hellofriends I am unaware of any closed form for $f(n)$ for integer $n$. The case $f(0)$ was mentioned and its exact value is an unanswered question here on MSE.

Comment: @mick can you link us the question to $f(0)$?

Comment: @hellofriends yes : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4664497/simplifying-a-complicated-continued-fraction-expression

I added it to the OP. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Using the @Yimin definition for `f[n,x]` and following with the commands `gr0 = Plot[f[16, x], {x, -20, 5}];gr1 = Plot[x + 2, {x, -20, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}];
Show[gr0, gr1]` we will depict the function plot. It seems that `-1.5185960265866827` is the only real root.

Comment: @Cesareo That is weird because for the first 5 or so truncated ones I get multiple roots and they do not come together. Then again, maybe they go to infinity or so. That could explain it.

Comment: I modified the title so that it includes something other than just math for technical reasons explained somewhere on Meta. Otherwise, have a nice day.

Comment: @BrunoB thanks +1

Answer (score 3):

Let's define the approximation function:

$$\tilde{f}(x) = \begin{cases} x + 1 + \frac{f(x+1)}{f(x+2)} & x < 10^6 \\ x + 2 & x \ge 10^6  \end{cases}$$

Here's an iterative Python implementation:

```
def f(x):
    if x >= 1000000:
        return x + 2
    ipart, fpart = divmod(x, 1)
    n = 999999
    next_values = (n + fpart + 3, n + fpart + 4)
    while True:
        y = n + fpart + 1 + next_values[0] / next_values[1]
        next_values = (y, next_values[0])
        if n == ipart:
            return y
        else:
            n -= 1
```

Using this definition to estimate $f$ for small values of $x$ (multiples of $0.01$ with $|x| \le 10$), the function appears to have a vertical asymptote between $-4.52$ and $-4.51$, and another one between $-3.52$ and $-3.51$.  There's also a sign change (but not at asymptote) between $-1.52$ and $-1.51$.

By gradually narrowing the search interval, I was able to find the exact (to IEEE double-precision) $x$ values:

- $x_1 \approx -4.518596026586683$
- $x_2 \approx -3.5185960265866827$
- $x_3 \approx -1.5185960265866827$

That all three “special” $x$ values have the same fractional part is surely no coincidence, but relates directly to the integer shifts of $x + 1$ and $x + 2$ in the definition of $f$.

So, the numerical answer to your question is $\boxed{t \approx -1.5185960265866827}$, as @Yimin previously noted in a comment.

---

I'm still trying to find a closed-form expression for $f$ or its root, but so far, no luck.

Comment: I could not understand why you need a rational approx for $f$ to get the root.

Comment: @Yimin: I was trying to find a closed-form expression for $f$, but can't get it working with 3rd/2nd degree polynomial.  Maybe it's 4th/3rd, or 5th/4th, or not a polynomial at all.

Comment: I upvoted this answer and Yimin's comment. Thank you guys. A closed form would be nice yes !  The position of poles is also a bit of a mystery.

Comment: I want to add that you guys have probably figured out the fixpoints from the above. This simplifies matters alot.